# Does tmux run-shell support interactive shell?

Tags: linux, tmux, interactive

I know tmux run-shell can execute shell:

```
$ tmux run-shell "echo start; echo \${var}end"
start
end
```

But what if I want my shell could work interactively or read some user input,

```
$ tmux run-shell "echo start; read -p \"prompt:\" var; echo \${var}end"
start
end
```

- Why read statement in above code doesn't work?
- Could any tmux expert let me know ways to implement interactive action with tmux?

Background:

- I put my various common work into a single `kit.sh` as functions all the time
- There are many interactive questions in this script
- Now I want to reuse this `kit.sh` with tmux hot key, as `bind-key i "run-shell \"kit.sh\""` in my .tmux.conf
- I'm planing to add some `tmux send-keys` in this `kit.sh` for kind of auto-type functions

**Update 20231016:**

My problem is solved as

```
bind-key i "new-window \"/path/to/my/kit.sh\""
```

And in kit.sh I can read user input interactively.

Comment: On runing `tmux run-shell "read VAR"` fails with read returning value `1`. You might want to read https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3187. It will be helpful if you could add what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @davidt930 please check my update

Answer (score 3):

`tmux run-shell` subcommand does not work with programs that require tty. This explains why `read` fails when running in interactive mode[1] and also why

```
tmux run-shell "echo start; read -p \"prompt:\" var; echo \${var}end"
```

fails.

As you have already guessed one way is to use `tmux send-keys`[2]. You can also use `split-window`[3]:

```
tmux split-window "read -p prompt: VAR; echo \$VAR; read -p \"press any key\""
```

If you are using `tmux` version `3.2` or above you can also use `display-popup` subcommand[2]

```
tmux display-popup "read -p prompt: VAR; echo \$VAR"
```

[0] https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3187#issuecomment-1127079855

[1] https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read

[2] https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3187

[3] https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3617#issuecomment-1627569000